# Prove that $(3n)!/(3!)^n$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $\frac{(3n)!}{(3!)^n}$ is an integer where $n$ is a non-negative integer. 
I can prove it with mathematical induction. Is there any other method?

Answer (score 3):

It's a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):
$$\frac{(3n)!}{3!}^n=\binom{3n}{3,3,\ldots,3},$$
and hence an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$3!=3\times 2$

$\displaystyle (3n)!=\prod_{k=1}^{3n}k=\prod_{i=1}^n(3i-2)\cdot\prod_{i=1}^n(3i-1)\cdot\prod_{i=1}^n(3i)$.

Here $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n(3i)=3^n(n!)$ is divisible by $3^n$.

$\displaystyle (3n)!=\prod_{k=1}^{3n}k=\prod_{k=2n+1}^{3n}k\cdot\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)\cdot\prod_{i=1}^n(2i)$.

Here $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n(2i)=2^n(n!)$ is divisible by $2^n$.

As $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime, $(3n)!$ is divisible by $3^n2^n=(3!)^n$.

Comment: I think you wrote one 3i-1 instead of 3i-2.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima My typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

What is $\displaystyle \binom{3n}{3} \times \binom{3n-3}{3} \times \binom{3n-6}{3} \times \binom{3n-9}{3} \times  \cdots \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{3}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

In the group of permutations of $A = \{1,2, \dots, n\} \times \{1,2,3\}$, the collection of permutations that leave each set $\{i\} \times \{1,2,3\}$ globally invariant forms a subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

$3!=6$, so you'd need to show $6^n$ divides $(3n)!$ directly.  I'd do this by grouping the terms of $(3n)!$ into n groups and showing $6$ divides each of them, or into $n/2$ groups and showing $36$ divides each.  To show divisibility by $6$, you can do $2$ and $3$ separately.